# Error with jboss7 migration

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss

**I am struggling with one problem while we are trying to deploy some ears into the different server versions as per clients interest, so that now i am trying to deploy our multiple ears into the jboss7.
The current problem is that datasources are bounded successfully as shown in below log**

```
16:18:47,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
16:18:47,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/OfflineDS]
16:18:47,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/JISPDS]
16:18:47,269 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/IntegrationViewDS]
16:18:47,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/IntegrationDS]
16:18:47,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/RATINGDS]
16:18:47,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/ChargingDS]
16:18:47,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/AccountDS]
16:18:47,273 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/RATINGDS]
16:18:47,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/OfflineInsertionDS]
16:18:47,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
```

**but it is giving some error some thing related to ds binding as shown in below log, if any of you please help me, atleast i am not able to analyse why this error is coming.
Thanx in advance.**

> 16:19:10,022 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 25893ms - Started 11864 of 12364 services (327 services failed or missing dependencies, 155 services are passive or on-demand)
>       16:19:10,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "system.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.SearchHolidaySessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.SearchHolidaySessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.ledger-new-ejb.SearchChargeHeadSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.ledger-new-ejb.SearchChargeHeadSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.DisplayConfigUtilSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.DisplayConfigUtilSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.ConnectionFatorySession.env.jms.BillPreviewAgentResponseQueuejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jms.BillPreviewAgentResponseQueueMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.ConnectionFatorySession.env.jms.BillPreviewAgentResponseQueuejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jms.BillPreviewAgentResponseQueue]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.CountrySearchSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.CountrySearchSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.TemplateSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.TemplateSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.flexfield-new-ejb.FlexFieldConfSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.flexfield-new-ejb.FlexFieldConfSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.StateSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.StateSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.SystemCommonSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.system.system-new-ejb.SystemCommonSessionBean.env.jdbc.JISPDSjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.JISPDS]",

Comment: Some of your dependent classes are not found, you may have mistakes in their JNDI name.

Comment: Yes you may right, actually we used the ejb2 beans, i didn't changed the name spaces, i kept those as like before only, is the problem about the namespace only???

if it is can you give an idea how i should change the namespaces exactly i tried different name spaces like SearchHolidaySessionBean(jboss5)-->java:global/system/system-new-ejb/SearchHolidaySessionBean(jboss7)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this, we know how much big problem it may be with single change it can be resolved, the same thing has been repeated here.

The thing is, in jboss7 while configuring ds we need to add java:\ or java:\jboss\ as prefix right!!! the same change we need to give at ejb-jar.xml while giving res-ref-name. or else you need to face these problems while you migrating from older jboss

I hope this may useful for My friends thank u.